# Django - RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Tags: python, django

I came across an error that was poorly explained when I wanted to customize the magic str function of my "ApiCall" model.

**My Model :**

```py
FOO = 1
FOO2 = 2
FOO3 = 3
ROUTES = (
    (FOO, "foo"),
    (FOO2, "foo 2"),
    (FOO3, "foo 3"),
)


class ApiCall(TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(MobileUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    route = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField('foo', choices=ROUTES)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"... {self.get_route_display}"
```

**Error :**

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Answer (score 1):

The problem is very simple but I find it badly explained, you just have to add parenthesis when you call the get_route_display function. like this :

```py
def __str__(self):
  return f"... {self.get_route_display()} ..."
```

PS: This function is automatically created from the "route" field in the model